# Indoor GPS presentation

Tags: android, ios, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

Whenever we go to present our Android/iOS apps to clients that use GPS, we always get incorrect GPS data (indoors and our apps fallback to Network location). Is there a quick way to 'fudge' GPS data for our client presentations?

Right now we always have to be sure to schedule meetings an extra 30 minutes to explain to the non-technical why GPS doesn't work indoors (whereas the app will be used 99.999% outdoors). In the end we always end up looking stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Explain that GPS doesn't work inside and then do your demo outside

BTW, bring references about why GPS doesn't work inside.

Answer (score 1):

Move all of your location code into its own class. Return fixed/chosen locations when in "demo" mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to explain to your client that GPS doesn't work well inside.  Honesty is far better than fudging it.  Plus, it shows that you actually know your stuff.

If you have to do it, put in static vars.  This requires you know the coords of your chosen location unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that describes using Mock Locations in Android. In Settings->Applications->Development, there 8is an option for "allow mock locations" - http://techxplorer.com/2011/07/01/using-mock-locations-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the location from Xcode.
You can run you app on device or simulator and simulate the location with Xcode Xcode->Product->Debug->Simulate Location
You can use the few locations already in Xcode or add custom locations or even load up a GPX file